# How to make a 50% transparent window?

Tags: firefox, transparency, xul

I'm trying to do a semi-transparent window. There's my attempt:

```xul
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    style="-moz-appearance: none;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            filter:alpha(opacity=50);
            opacity: 0.5;
            -moz-opacity:0.5;"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="MAIN WINDOW"/>

</window>
```

Although the text on the window is transparent, the window itself is not.

I've read that it works only for panels, not windows, so I tried it with both `<panel>` and `<window>` but none of then become transparent.

I've tried the approaches used [here](http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-transparency.php), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981705/css-create-a-transparent-div), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057897/writing-a-firefox-extension-to-show-frameless-transparent-window). But nothing works.

Any idea?

I just realized that while dragging a tab in Firefox 3.6.10, it shows a transparent window. I just need to know how it's done now.

Comment: style="-moz-appearance: none; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); opacity: 0.5;" worked for me on Windows when I tried it, but maybe it doesn't work on all platforms?

Comment: @Neil not on Ubuntu 10.04, using Xulrunner 1.9.2.14. The opacity affects only the content of the window, not the window background itself.

Comment: Indeed, setting the opacity: 0.5; only affected the text, but combining that with the background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); gave me a 50% transparent window.

Comment: @Neil, right, not my case as you can see in my code. Maybe there's some issue with xulrunner and transparency for linux? I'll search about..

Comment: Didn't work in my Linux VM either. Maybe you need to install a composite manager.

Comment: @Neil Ubuntu already have one, the Compiz.

Comment: @Neil there is someone talking about a problem with transparency after a Xulrunner update [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/bug-488719-xulrunner-1-9-bad-transparency-progress-mill-icon-help-167995451.html).

Comment: @Tom Brito Sorry, that's not relevant, that's just Debian not being able to support APNG files (Mozilla official Xulrunner has a custom PNG library to do this).

Comment: @Neil what about [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=415618)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of poking around and found [bug 408284](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408284), which sadly isn't fixed even for Gecko 2. So it's not possible on Linux.

Comment: I just realized that while dragging a tab in Firefox 3.6.10, it shows a transparent window. I just need to know how it's done now..

Comment: It's not a transparent window, it's a drag cursor, using gdk_drag_set_icon_pixmap. (So this proves that you're using a compositor, otherwise it would use gdk_drag_set_icon_pixbuf which is opaque.)